# JVM language with easy in use UI framework

Tags: java

i'm looking for some JVM language (it can be just language with JVM implementation, like Python, but i more interested in "native" JVM languages, like Scala or Groovy) with really easy framework for UI. Not Web UI, i want to create Desktop application. And yes, i know that Java isn't best choose for Apps, UI and such things, but for now i interested only in Java related technologies, and really tired writing command-line apps.

Comment: Could you please describe a bit more what you don't like in Swing/SWT/JavaFX?

Comment: Well, maybe i should give them another try, but they look's... too low-level and takes me into details of UI, I looks for some framework that provides higher level of abstraction. Like Hibernate, that hides details of JDBC.

Comment: Could you name a GUI technology that you like? (even if it is not relevant to your current needs, it might give us an idea of what kind of simplicity you are after)

Comment: Also, what GUI do you want to implement? If it is just managing JavaBeans (CRUD) there are easy options, for instance.

Comment: If your interest in Java is a desire to run cross-platform, then check out the [Xojo](https://www.xojo.com/) toolset as an alternative way to build desktop apps in an object-oriented language and deploy across macOS, Windows, Linux, iOS, and more. No JVM involved as your app compiles to run natively on each of the deployment targets.